# How to get name of files which are not copied?

Tags: php

I have copied a number of PDF files from one directory to another directory. Unfortunately, some file have not been copied, and I want to identify those files.

For this purpose I want to write a PHP program which finds those files. What I have so far is a program which compares file names, but I want to check for file size. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: 1. at the time of scan the directory, add all the file names to an array(say `$all_files_array`).2. at the time of copy, in that copy code add the file name to another array(say `$copied_files`). at the last take the difference(`array_diff($all_files_array,$copied_files)`) and you will come to know which files are not copied.

Comment: Language improved.